# How to trim parameters in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up a parameterized Jenkins job with pipeline. I need to trim trim parameters any suggestions?

In New version of Jenkins i can able to get the parameters. But I can't modify the parameters. If i use `setValue()`, it gives me `unsupportedException`.

Answer (score 25):

```
parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "", description: '', name: 'tag or commit', trim: true)
}
```

Comment: The "trim" is not in the jenkins doc https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters
You may find from the codes? @Aakizone

Comment: It seems they have postponed documenting it, seemingly indefinitely. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/INFRA-1053

Comment: 2017/11/12 | https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-47115 | https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-old/#:~:text=What%27s%20new%20in%202.90%20(2017%2D11%2D12)

Comment: INFRA issues moved to GitHub on 2022-01-11, thus the up-to-date link for INFRA-1053 is: https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/issues/5221

Answer (score 3):

Which type of parameter are You using? Is it user input or some kind of choice list? As workaround You can use another variable:

```
myVar = param1.trim()
```

then You can use myVar instead o param1

Comment: Hi Robert, I am using Extended choice parameter(TextArea choice parameter).Actually parameter is key value pair. i need to trim only value.

Comment: Declarative pipeline or advanced scripted?

Comment: advanced scripted